# Not getting any data from api controller into vue component

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-8, vuejs3, laravel-mix-vue3

I have a component in vue 3 named index which gets the user form data and passes it onto api controller in laravel.

```
async submitForm() {
  try {
    await axios.post(
      "/api/show",
      {
        firstname: this.form.firstname,
        email: this.form.email,
      },
    );
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("error");
  }
 
},
```

and I'm trying to fetch the data sent into the controller via following method onto another component named show and all I'm getting is empty string and I don't understand the reason.  Any guide would be really appreciated.

```
   loadProductDetails() {
    axios.post("api/show")
    .then(({data}) => (this.products = data));
    
},
```

Comment: First be sure that your server side is working and in this case it stored data. next you can debug what happens when you are fetching stored data from the server side.

Comment: I tested the server side. the data is being shown in the controller and I'm returning it as a json response but the fetch code just returns empty string.

Comment: The fetch code is sending a POST request, if you are GETting data it should normally be a GET. Why are you using a mixture of fetch and axios? you can just use axios.get()

Edit: plus if you use axios and the response header has application/json it will automatically parse into json

Comment: when I use GET to fetch the data into the component it gives me the error of method not allowed as I'm using POST in the route to submit the data into the controller. I tried to modify the code as modified above to axios, it just returns the same empty string as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue. It was because I was trying to get response from two different routes but the first one was already fetching the post response data and second one was returning the empty string and replacing the data I already recieved from the response.

```
   try {
    axios
      .post("/api/show", {
        firstname: this.form.firstname,
        email: this.form.email,
        selectedAnswer: this.form.selectedAnswer,
        selectedCategory: this.form.selectedCategory,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        localStorage.setItem("show", JSON.stringify(res.data));
      });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("error");
  }
```

Simply saving the response data into local storage and getting it from another component solved the issue.

```
loadProductDetails() {
    this.products = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('show'));
}
```